# for...in loop and prototype-chain

Tags: javascript

we kown for..in loop does not care if the property is the attribute of object's prototype-chain .so it will output the attribute all.
and let us do a test

```
var o={};
for(var i in o){
    console.log(o[i]);//  output  none
}
```

a object(created by this way:{}) is from Object,
but when we run the code,the Object prototype-chain method (like toString )is not outputed
why the method (toString) in prototype-chain of Object is not outputed ????

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`toString` is not [enumerable](http://es5.github.com/#x8.6.1):

```
("toString" in {}) === true
({}).propertyIsEnumerable("toString") === false
```

You can create your own non-enumerable properties like so:

```
var object = {};

Object.defineProperty(object, "property", { enumerable: false, value: 5 });
```

<sub>Technically you can omit the `enumerable: false`, since that is the default.</sub>

---

This is indicated [in the spec](http://es5.github.com/#x15) in the blanket section 15 clause:

> In every case, the length property of a built-in `Function` object described in this clause has the attributes `{ [[Writable]]: false, [[Enumerable]]: false, [[Configurable]]: false }`. **Every other property described in this clause has the attributes `{ [[Writable]]: true, [[Enumerable]]: false, [[Configurable]]: true }` unless otherwise specified.**